# Doctrine2 conversion error

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

What does this error from "Doctrine2 & Symfony2" mean?

> Could not convert database value "" to Doctrine Type array

Answer (score 78, accepted):

You probably changed a field from type string to type array in your entity but already have data the database. It's failing at trying to convert an empty string from the database to an array.

If it's a development database, simply delete it and create it again, or just delete the offending rows. Or you could convert all the empty strings to `a:0:{}` (a serialized empty array).

```
UPDATE table SET column="a:0:{}" WHERE column = "";
```

Comment: Had this same issue. Occurred after I added a field to an Entity that had preexisting data. Doctrine tries to convert NULL to an array, instead of intelligently seeing that the field is NULL so it should simply return an empty array ;) Setting the preexisting entries to a serialized empty array worked perfectly. +1

Comment: Thanks for the solution @solarc - I needed the UPDATE clause for my `roles` field which was empty after importing users from an existing project: http://blog.webdevilopers.net/fosuserbundle-login-error-could-not-convert-database-value-to-doctrine-type-array/

Comment: OR you can set the field to null with `N;`

Answer (score 8):

I would prefer not having everyone running SQL on their Production Database.

```
 @ORM\Column(type="array", nullable=TRUE)
```

An easier solution in make the Column nullable, so after you run your "console doctrine:schema:update --force" the existing DB entries will get a NULL value, instead of an empty string.  And doctrine can handle a converting the database value NULL to Doctrine Type array.  It should be just a NULL array reference.  And PHP empty() doesn't care if its zero sized array or NULL.

In MySQL, I get the following sql-dump:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table ADD my_new_column LONGTEXT DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '(DC2Type:array)'
```

Comment: though I have the same sql-dump, this did not work for me as i am getting the same error.

Comment: Nice tip! Sadly, I had aleady tried the solution above, and was stuck with a lot of fields with empty string instead of NULL.

I solved that issue by running this statement:
app/console doctrine:query:sql "UPDATE <<your_table_name>> SET <<field_name>> = NULL  WHERE <<field_name>>=''"

Answer (score 0):

You can add new Type like that:

```
use Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\AbstractPlatform;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\ArrayType;

class HandicappedArrayType extends ArrayType
{
    public function convertToPHPValue($value, AbstractPlatform $platform)
    {
        if ($value === null || $value === '') {
            return null;
        }

        return parent::convertToPHPValue($value, $platform);
    }
```

Answer (score -5):

your db tables column type (eg: longtext) can't match Doctrine's column type.
change column type.