# Symfony 2 error message

Tags: php, forms, symfony, runtime-error

I have a form with a drop down and a set of checkboxes, i've used entity form field type to get the values via DB. it works with one of the entity but not with the other. i have this code seperately inside *AddBadgesType*
there is NO AddBadges entity

```
<?php
namespace Test\Bundle\TestBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;

class AddBadgesType extends AbstractType
{
 /**
  * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
  * @param array $options
  */
 public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array   $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('property', 'entity', array(
            'class' => 'TestBundle:Property',
            'property' => 'id',
            'query_builder' => function (\Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository $er) {
                return $er->createQueryBuilder('property')
                    ->orderBy('property.id ', 'ASC');
            },
        ))
        ->add('badges', 'entity', array(
                'class' => 'TestBundle:Badge',
                'property' => 'name',
                'multiple' => true,
                'expanded' => true,
            ))
        ;
}

/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getName()
{
    return 'test_bundle_testbundle_AddBadges';
}
}
```

with this error

> Could not convert database value "" to Doctrine Type array

here is the enity for property

```
<?php

 namespace Test\Bundle\TestBundle\Entity;

 use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
 use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
 use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
  /**
   * Property
   *
   * @ORM\Table()
   * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Test\Bundle\TestBundle\Entity\PropertyRepository")
   */
 class Property
 {
public function __construct() {
    $this->campus = new ArrayCollection();
    $this->tag = new ArrayCollection();
}

/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;



/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="University", inversedBy="property")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="university_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $university;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Tag")
 */
private $tag;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="badges", type="array")
 */
private $badges;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Campus")
 */
private $campus;

/**
 * @var string
 * @ORM\Column(name="address", type="string", length=255)
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 * @Assert\Length(
 *                 min = 10,
 *                 max = 80,
 *                 minMessage = "Address must be more specific",
 *                 maxMessage = "80 characters limit exceeded"
 *              )
 */
private $address;

/**
 * @var integer
 * @ORM\Column(name="postalcode", type="integer")
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 * @Assert\Length(
 *                 min = 3,
 *                 minMessage = "Password must contain atleast 3 digits"
 *              )
 */
private $postalcode;

/**
 * @var integer
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 * @ORM\Column(name="propertytype", type="integer")
 */
private $propertytype;

/**
 * @var integer
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 * @ORM\Column(name="rent", type="integer")
 */
private $rent;

/**
 * @var integer
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 * @ORM\Column(name="leaseperiod", type="integer")
 */
private $leaseperiod;

/**
 * @var integer
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 * @ORM\Column(name="utilities", type="integer")
 */
private $utilities;

/**
 * @var integer
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 * @ORM\Column(name="bedrooms", type="integer")
 */
private $bedrooms;

/**
 * @var integer
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 * @ORM\Column(name="bathrooms", type="integer")
 */
private $bathrooms;

/**
 * @var string
 * @ORM\Column(name="additionaldetails", type="string", length=255)
 * @Assert\Length(
 *                 min = 10,
 *                 max = 200,
 *                 minMessage = "Details must be more specific",
 *                 maxMessage = "200 characters limit exceeded"
 *              )
 */
private $additionaldetails;


/**
 * Get id
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set address
 *
 * @param string $address
 * @return Property
 */
public function setAddress($address)
{
    $this->address = $address;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get address
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getAddress()
{
    return $this->address;
}

/**
 * Set postalcode
 *
 * @param string $postalcode
 * @return Property
 */
public function setPostalcode($postalcode)
{
    $this->postalcode = $postalcode;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get postalcode
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getPostalcode()
{
    return $this->postalcode;
}

/**
 * Set propertytype
 *
 * @param integer $propertytype
 * @return Property
 */
public function setPropertytype($propertytype)
{
    $this->propertytype = $propertytype;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get propertytype
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getPropertytype()
{
    return $this->propertytype;
}

/**
 * Set rent
 *
 * @param string $rent
 * @return Property
 */
public function setRent($rent)
{
    $this->rent = $rent;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get rent
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getRent()
{
    return $this->rent;
}

/**
 * Set leaseperiod
 *
 * @param integer $leaseperiod
 * @return Property
 */
public function setLeaseperiod($leaseperiod)
{
    $this->leaseperiod = $leaseperiod;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get leaseperiod
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getLeaseperiod()
{
    return $this->leaseperiod;
}

/**
 * Set utilities
 *
 * @param integer $utilities
 * @return Property
 */
public function setUtilities($utilities)
{
    $this->utilities = $utilities;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get utilities
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getUtilities()
{
    return $this->utilities;
}

/**
 * Set bedrooms
 *
 * @param integer $bedrooms
 * @return Property
 */
public function setBedrooms($bedrooms)
{
    $this->bedrooms = $bedrooms;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get bedrooms
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getBedrooms()
{
    return $this->bedrooms;
}

/**
 * Set bathrooms
 *
 * @param integer $bathrooms
 * @return Property
 */
public function setBathrooms($bathrooms)
{
    $this->bathrooms = $bathrooms;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get bathrooms
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getBathrooms()
{
    return $this->bathrooms;
}

/**
 * Set additionaldetails
 *
 * @param string $additionaldetails
 * @return Property
 */
public function setAdditionaldetails($additionaldetails)
{
    $this->additionaldetails = $additionaldetails;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get additionaldetails
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getAdditionaldetails()
{
    return $this->additionaldetails;
}

/**
 * Set university
 *
 * @param \Test\Bundle\TestBundle\Entity\Univerisity $university
 * @return Property
 */
public function setUniversity(\Test\Bundle\TestBundle\Entity\University $university = null)
{
    $this->university = $university;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get university
 *
 * @return \Test\Bundle\TestBundle\Entity\Univerisity 
 */
public function getUniversity()
{
    return $this->university;
}

/**
 * Add campus
 *
 * @param \Test\Bundle\TestBundle\Entity\Campus $campus
 * @return Property
 */
public function addCampus(\Test\Bundle\TestBundle\Entity\Campus $campus)
{
    $this->campus[] = $campus;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Remove campus
 *
 * @param \Test\Bundle\TestBundle\Entity\Campus $campus
 */
public function removeCampus(\Test\Bundle\TestBundle\Entity\Campus $campus)
{
    $this->campus->removeElement($campus);
}

/**
 * Get campus
 *
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
 */
public function getCampus()
{
    return $this->campus;
}

/**
 * Add tag
 *
 * @param \Test\Bundle\TestBundle\Entity\Tag $tag
 * @return Property
 */
public function addTag(\Test\Bundle\TestBundle\Entity\Tag $tag)
{
    $this->tag[] = $tag;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Remove tag
 *
 * @param \Test\Bundle\TestBundle\Entity\Tag $tag
 */
public function removeTag(\Test\Bundle\TestBundle\Entity\Tag $tag)
{
    $this->tag->removeElement($tag);
}

/**
 * Get tag
 *
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
 */
public function getTag()
{
    return $this->tag;
}

/**
 * Set badges
 *
 * @param array $badges
 * @return Property
 */
public function setBadges($badges)
{
    $this->badges = $badges;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get badges
 *
 * @return array 
 */
public function getBadges()
{
    return $this->badges;
}
}
```

However if i change the entity to 'Campus' it works fine, i think it might be something to do with the ManyToMany relationship in property entity?!

Campus entity for reference

```
<?php

 namespace Test\Bundle\TestBundle\Entity;

 use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
 use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

 /**
  * Campus
  *
  * @ORM\Table()
  * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Test\Bundle\TestBundle\Entity\CampusRepository")
  */
 class Campus
{
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="University", inversedBy="campus")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="university_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $university;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
 * @Assert\NotBlank
 * @Assert\Length(
 *                  min=3,
 *                  max=35,
 *                  minMessage= "Name Field should contains at least 3 characters",
 *                  maxMessage = "Name Field Cannot contain more than 35 characters"
 *               )
 * @Assert\Regex(pattern="/[^a-z\s-]/i", match=false , message="Name can only contain letters")
 */
private $name;

/**
 * @var string
 * @ORM\Column(name="address", type="string", length=255)
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 * @Assert\Length(
 *                 min = 10,
 *                 max = 80,
 *                 minMessage = "Address must be more specific",
 *                 maxMessage = "80 characters limit exceeded"
 *              )
 */
private $address;


/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set name
 *
 * @param string $name
 * @return Campus
 */
public function setName($name)
{
    $this->name = $name;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get name
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getName()
{
    return $this->name;
}

/**
 * Set address
 *
 * @param string $address
 * @return Campus
 */
public function setAddress($address)
{
    $this->address = $address;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get address
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getAddress()
{
    return $this->address;
}

/**
 * Set university
 *
 * @param \Test\Bundle\TestBundle\Entity\University $university
 * @return Campus
 */
public function setUniversity(\Test\Bundle\TestBundle\Entity\University $university = null)
{
    $this->university = $university;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get university
 *
 * @return \Test\Bundle\TestBundle\Entity\University 
 */
public function getUniversity()
{
    return $this->university;
}
```

}

Comment: Does your `PropertyRepository` class extend `EntityRepository`? And did you `use` the right `EntityRepository`'s namespace at the beginning of your files?

Comment: Please show path and name of the file and namespace statements, maybe there is something wrong with them.

Comment: @michal.hubczyk noting wrong with the namespaces and file names, i've checked, becides it works with a different entity, so its not the namespaces issue

Comment: Yup updated the code as you asked guys...

Comment: Does your `PropertyRepository` class extend `EntityRepository`? And you haven't `use` the right `EntityRepository`'s namespace at the beginning of your file (the one containing the form).

Comment: @noobDeDaa It really would be better to revert your question to it's original state and post a new question because 1) the title no longer matches the question (although that can be fixed), 2) the answer no longer makes any sense 3) related to 2 - this Q&A is no longer useful to any other users, which is half the point of this site 4) the more questions you post the more likely you are to accrue reputation and privileges and 5) once a question has an answer (accepted or not) it is unlikely to receive further attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not included the Symfony EnityRepository class at the top of your form file so PHP is looking for it in the same directory as your form class. Hence the error message. Add this to your form class (or qualify EntityRepository inline):

```
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
```

Comment: i have't customised the Property Repository, it does extend EntityRepository with the proper namespaces

Comment: Edited answer - it's not extension that's the problem, it's not finding the EntityRepository class at all.

Comment: You should have looked for an answer / tried to fix that yourself and then posted a new question if you couldn't. A google search for that error message brings up this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8818387/doctrine2-conversion-error

Comment: yea your answer worked out, its all good. what do i do now? delete this question? you guys dont mess around! this is pretty serious place :o

Comment: _what do i do now?_ - I'd suggest undoing your edit to this question. The down votes are likely due to you having two questions in one post. It's also considered good form to [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) the answer that helps you.